# Does Islam have a flag?

Tags: caliph, symbolism

There are many narrations where the Allah's Apostle (salallahu alayhi wassalam) mentions "flag" like the following one:

> Narrated Anas:
>
> The Prophet had informed the people of the martyrdom of Zaid, Ja'far
>   and Ibn Rawaha before the news of their death reached. The Prophet
>   said, "Zaid took the flag (as the commander of the army) and was
>   martyred, then Ja`far took it and was martyred, and then Ibn Rawaha
>   took it and was martyred." At that time the Prophet's eyes were
>   shedding tears. He added, "Then **the flag** was taken by a Sword
>   amongst the Swords of Allah (i.e. Khalid) and Allah made them (i.e.
>   the Muslims) victorious." **Sahih Al-Bukhari Book 64, Hadith 4307**

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_flags) says "An Islamic flag is a flag that complies with Islamic rules."

My question is "Does Islam have a flag?" and "What are the rules for the flag?"

Answers with scholarly opinion based on Qur'an and Hadith preferred.

Comment: Retagged. See no reason for [jihad].

Comment: Is there a reason for [jihad] or [caliph]?

Comment: @Dynamic I couldn't find more appropriate tag. Jihad because when the Prophet went for Jihad, he had a flag. Caliph because the Caliphs used to have a flag when they went for military expeditions.

Answer (score 2):

> يُحَدِّثُ عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ، قَالَ كَانَتْ رَايَةُ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ
>   صلى الله عليه وسلم سَوْدَاءَ وَلِوَاؤُهُ أَبْيَضَ . قَالَ أَبُو عِيسَى
>   هَذَا حَدِيثٌ حَسَنٌ غَرِيبٌ مِنْ هَذَا الْوَجْهِ مِنْ حَدِيثِ ابْنِ
>   عَبَّاسٍ . ...
>
> Narrated Ibn 'Abbas: "The flag of the Messenger of Allah (saws) was
>   black, and his standard was white." [Abu 'Eisa said:] This Hadith is
>   Hasan Gharib from this route, as a narration of Ibn 'Abbas.

and

> حَدَّثَنَا يُونُسُ بْنُ عُبَيْدٍ، مَوْلَى مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ الْقَاسِمِ
>   قَالَ بَعَثَنِي مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ الْقَاسِمِ إِلَى الْبَرَاءِ بْنِ
>   عَازِبٍ أَسْأَلُهُ عَنْ رَايَةِ، رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم
>   فَقَالَ كَانَتْ سَوْدَاءَ مُرَبَّعَةً مِنْ نَمِرَةٍ .
>
> Narrated Yunus bin 'Ubaid: the freed salve of Muhammad bin Al-Qasim
>   said: "Muhammad bin Al-Qasim sent me to Al-Bara' bin 'Azib to ask him
>   about the flag of the Messenger of Allah (saws). He said: 'It was a
>   black square of Namirah.'"

Of of these ahaadeeth it is clear that flag the Messenger of Allah -peace be upon him -was black and her name flag punishment, and is said to have been written on it (is no god but God and Mohammed is the Messenger of God), and this is the flag that was brought by all Muslims is the flag of Islam, and was his brigade white, so  flag that placed on the headquarters of the Muslims or the the headquarters of the caliph, where he was Brigade is white,
and is said to it also had written on it (is no god but God and Mohammed is the Messenger of Allah),and it  has remained the flag symbol of the Muslims flying since the time of the Prophet peace be upon him until the end of the state Ottoman 1342 AH, 1924.